# Android: How to create a direct download link in android

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, download, android-download-manager

Can anyone give me an idea on how to create a textview which has a link and when the user click it, the file from that link will be automatically downloaded by the device

EDIT:

here's the code were working on:

```
String link = "http://www.exampleurl.com/"+pref.getString("fsfile" + count, null);
    link = link.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    fsfile.setText("Attached File");
    fsfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(link);
        }
    });
```

but it seems the `String link` is not identified inside the `.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Here is our code Mr. @Avadhani Y. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Here is our code Mr. @Avadhani Y

Comment: Declare String `link` as global variable. That should work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats quite easy
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Example: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/android-download-manager-example.html

And start this method after clicking the textview (Catch with Handler or listener)

```
/**
 * Start Download
 */
public void startDownload() {
    DownloadManager mManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request mRqRequest = new Request(
            Uri.parse("http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-webview-loading-custom-html-and.html"));
    mRqRequest.setDescription("This is Test File");
//  mRqRequest.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("give your local path"));
    long idDownLoad=mManager.enqueue(mRqRequest);
}
```

But be sure you are min. on API 9

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code onclick of TextView:

```
<Your TextView>.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(<Your URL String>);
        }
    });
```

**DownloadFromURL.java**

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread
 * Show Progress Bar Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}

/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
  }

/**
 * After completing background task
 * Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    // Displaying downloaded image into image view
    // Reading image path from sdcard
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
    // setting downloaded into image view
    my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
}

}
```