# How to download files from an ASP.NET site on Android?

Tags: java, android

i'm building app to site which is built on ASP.NET, this downloadmanager not work:

```
            @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".doc")) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(
                        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                String fileName = "Документ" + url.startsWith(".");
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                DownloadManager dManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dManager.enqueue(request);
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Download button code:

```
<a href="JavaScript:openAttachment('/doc/28-02-2019.xlsx', 283662);">28-02-2019.xlsx</a>
```

Comment: what error message you are getting on Android?

Comment: no messages, just nothing downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can download file from your web browser the follow this answer :
[Android: How to create a direct download link in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611326/android-how-to-create-a-direct-download-link-in-android)